# Spring rest service in websphere 8.5.5.10 gives Path Not Found

Tags: spring, websphere, mybatis, spring-restcontroller

I am building a Spring 4 , mybatis rest services in WebSphere 8.5.5.10 with Maven. I generated WAR using POM maven and deployed in WebSphere. WAR deployed properly, when I try to hit the path it gives me Not Found. If I hit context root alone I get index.jsp properly. Only rest path is not detected. Following is the error I get in postman.

```
http://localhost:9083/ewalletAdpt/profile/373745698
Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /profile/373745698
```

FFDC logs

```
[12/20/19 10:29:03:986 PST]     FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -IOE ProbeId:1044
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /profile/373745698
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor._processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.processEDR(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:957)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3951)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1014)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

Reporter:null
```

Comment: Please show the service definition, where you assign the `/profile` path and "id" subpath below that.